# about adding db header file to my project that build with ninja

Tags: postgresql, ninja, postgresql-10

i have a project that build successfully with ninja, now i want to add some code that work with database (like PostgreSQL) too. but after i do config (like adding header file to project configuration correctly that even DB work in simple example project too) , my compiler find it but in build time ninja get error that can not found header files.

how can add extra library for ninja?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to include enough content for someone to reproduce the issue in the body of the question (without external links). Also, if you are getting an error, include the traceback. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok, i edit my question to explain better @SuperShoot